# How to convert CSV to JSON-Python

Tags: python, json, firebase, csv, stream

I am having trouble converting a url from a csv file to json, change whatever changes anything always shows me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:/Users/Gamer/Downloads/TimingReady/PC/archivos/prueba.py", line 8, in 
>       with open(csvUrl) as csvFile:
>   OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://localhost/_144141/api/0WUFVJB4ZTBENW5F6JT3QAUV4ASMRH10.csv'

My code is as follows:

```
            import csv
            import json

            csvUrl = input("Paste the event URL: ")
            jsonFinal = "jsonEvento.json"

            data = {}
            with open(csvUrl) as csvFile:
                csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
                for csvRow in csvReader:
                    Place = csvRow["Place"]
                    data[Place] = csvRow

            root = {}
            roo["Participantes"] = data

            with open(jsonFinal, "w") as jsonFile:
                jsonFile.write(json.dumps(root, indent=4))
```

And the CSV file is as follows:

> "Place";"Chip";"Numero";"Apellido";"Nombre";"Tiempo"
>   "1.";"739";"139";"MARTINEZ GUTIERREZ";"JOSE";"00:30:12,91"
>   "2.";"707";"107";"SUAREZ MORERA";"DANIEL";"02:00:17,54"
>   "3.";"1686";"274";"RODRIGUEZ VARGAS";"JOSE LUIS";"02:01:09,09"
>   "4.";"761";"161";"GONZALEZ MORENO";"MAURICIO ALBERTO";"02:03:18,29"
>   "5.";"775";"175";"HERNANDEZ";"ALEJANDRO";"02:05:05,93"
>   "6.";"1709";"297";"CASTILLO";"JOSE GREGORIO";"02:09:51,26"
>   "7.";"721";"121";"TELLEZ CRUZ";"CARLOS ALBERTO";"02:11:08,34"
>   "8.";"1711";"299";"MEDINA JARAMILLO";"JEFERSON";"02:12:26,48"
>   "9.";"766";"166";"JIMENEZ";"FRANCE ELIAS";"02:12:44,48"
>   "10.";"1671";"259";"GOMEZ PRIETO";"JEAN JENNER";"02:14:03,54"
>   "11.";"778";"178";"CAMPO SARMIENTO";"JOSE FRANCISCO";"02:15:45,05"
>   "12.";"1702";"290";"BUITRAGO HERNANDEZ";"NORBEY";"02:15:45,49"

Which I need in JSON like this

```
            {
                "nombreEvento": "Intercontinental Sunset Cartagena",
                "participantes": [
                    {
                    "Apellido": "MARTINEZ GUTIERREZ",
                    "Chip": 739,
                    "Nombre": "JOSE",
                    "Numero": 139,
                    "Place": "1.",
                    "Tiempo": "00:30:12,91"
                    },
                    {
                    "Apellido": "SUAREZ MORERA",
                    "Chip": 707,
                    "Nombre": "DANIEL",
                    "Numero": 107,
                    "Place": "2.",
                    "Tiempo": "02:00:17,54"
                    },
                    {
                    "Apellido": "RODRIGUEZ VARGAS",
                    "Chip": 1686,
                    "Nombre": "JOSE LUIS",
                    "Numero": 274,
                    "Place": "3.",
                    "Tiempo": "02:01:09,09"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I want to make Python stream the csv file in real time to json.

Answer (score 0):

What I can read from your error message is that your code can't access the file. This is because the open() function can only read/write files from your local drive. If you want to get a file from an api for example (even if it's localhost) you need another package to do so. Checkout this guide in order to get the csv file you need: https://www.powercms.in/blog/how-get-json-data-remote-url-python-script

I would advise when coding to create the app step by step. So first start with getting the csv to load, by printing it to your console. Once that is working continue on to translating it to a json format.

Updated final solution for this specific case:

```
import csv
import json
from io import StringIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = input("Pega aqui la URL de RaceResult: ")
data = []
final = {}

csvfile = urlopen(url).read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
datafile = StringIO(csvfile)

csvReader = csv.DictReader(datafile, delimiter=';')
for csvRow in csvReader:
    print(csvRow)
    data.append(csvRow)

final['nombreEvento'] = "Intercontinental Sunset Cartagena"
final['participantes'] = data
jsonFinal = "jsonEvento.json"
with open(jsonFinal, "w") as jsonFile:
   jsonFile.write(json.dumps(final, indent=4))
```

Comment: The script already works, but now when it converts the file to Json, the fields are added a "\"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Timo Frionnet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10582347/timo-frionnet)

In my case I needed a manual way to add the "EventName" and also a URL because the program I use does not provide me with the facility of a RestApi

```
            import csv
            import json
            from io import StringIO
            from urllib.request import urlopen

            url = input("Pega aqui la URL de RaceResult: ")
            data = []
            final = {}

            csvfile = urlopen(url).read().decode('ascii', 'ignore')
            datafile = StringIO(csvfile)

            csvReader = csv.DictReader(datafile, delimiter=';')
            for csvRow in csvReader:
                print(csvRow)
                data.append(csvRow)

            final['nombreEvento'] = input("Escribe el Nombre del Evento: ")
            final['participantes'] = data
            jsonFinal = "jsonEvento.json"
            with open(jsonFinal, "w") as jsonFile:
               jsonFile.write(json.dumps(final, indent=4))
```